# Enable users to change the owner of a case that does not belong to them

Tags: administration, profile, sharing-rule

I have an org in which a profile had a sharing setting on the cases that permit the users to see and modify all cases (not only the ones they own). The profile have the rights to read, create, modify ans show all for the case, they don't have the right to delete the cases (so they havn't the modify all permission).

But I need them to be able to modify the owner of the case, even if the case does not belong to them. Is that even possible to do that in the salesforce setup ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Transfer Cases" permission will give you the access you are looking for.

You can find some information here:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000175883&type=1
And here:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_about_transfer.htm&type=5